# Backslash in multipart boundary attribute

Tags: apache, http

What is the expected behaviour when a backslash occurs in a multipart boundary attribute? The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) (section 5.1.1) does not allow it, however, Apache seem to understand this request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="\foo"
Content-Length: 74

--\foo
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bar"

baz
--\foo--
```

To me, the boundary interpreted by Apache should be "foo", not "\foo" as the backslash escape the 'f' and the post variable "bar" should not be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed right, the syntax given in [section 5.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) does not allow for backslashes here. Through [RFC 822, section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3.3) you are also right in expecting `\f` to be a presentation of `f` within a quoted string.

However, in reality implementations are hardly performing any translations beyond `\"` → `"`. Due to a lot of clients with very … [unique ideas](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eeryq/MIME-tools-6.200_01/lib/MIME/Tools/traps.pod#Inability_to_handle_multipart_boundaries_with_embedded_newlines) on what is and what isn't a valid boundary, peers have a tendency to be very forgiving with what they are being fed and just take the boundary verbatim, which is what I believe Apache is doing here.

So if everything went strictly by the book, the expected behaviour here were to:

- let Apache take the request (for the sake of the argument let's assume Apache were processing it itself, which is rarely ever happening with `POST` requests),
- parse the metadata,
- find that that the content consists of multiple parts delimited by `\foo`,
- conclude that the delimiter in the message body must be `--foo<CR><LF>`,
- realize said delimiter never actually appears in the body, and
- produce a [400 / Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) status code as the message body seems to be corrupted

Comment: I had the feeling Apache was very permissive, Nginx does the same actually. I understand your point but this is a surprising behaviour and I really wonder if Apache wanted it or if it is just a mistake. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @JeffBencteux Well, MIME is quite old and implementations vary wildly. I also suspect most implementors do not bother to read the RFCs carefully, so MIME parsers have to be rather liberal with their input. If you're interested, read [this blog post](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-decoding-rfc2047-encoded-headers-is.html) about the challenges in decoding headers and [this rant](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/09/time-for-rant-on-mime-parsers.html) on parsers.